# Docker Unauthorized when pulling

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have tried pulling my files numerous times on Windows 10, but right when it begins extracting a certain large file (1.3G), it halts and says 'unauthorized'.

I have tried fixing this issue by going to Docker -> Setting -> Shared, but 'Shared' does not pop up.

I even created an account on hub.docker.com, logged on, then ran it, but the same thing happened.

As a last resort, I then uninstalled docker and reinstalled it - still does not work.

Has anyone encounter these issues/does anyone know what to do from here?

Thank you

***Edit for clarification***

I am pulling from dockerhub: https://hub.docker.com/r/jimiucb1/i526-aml

The command is: `docker pull jimiucb1/i526-aml`

Comment: are you trying to pull from docker hub or some other registry?

Comment: What image are you pulling? Show the full command and output (as formatted text, not a screenshot). Is there a network proxy intercepting requests?

Comment: worked fine here. Do a `docker logout` to clear out any existing auth creds and try the docker pull again